# How to Convert data From CSV to JSON?

Tags: apex, json, csv

I am trying to create a Records from CSV File to Custom Object.

This is my Method

```
 public Pagereference ReadFile()
    {

        NameFile1 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contentFile);

        string[] htm  = new String[]{}; 
          htm= nameFile.split('\t');


        filelines = nameFile.split('\n');
        system.debug('AAAAAAA'+filelines );
        orderstoupload = new List<Order__C>();
        for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
        {
            String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
            inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');
            Order__C a = new Order__C();
            a.FSN__C = inputvalues[0];
            a.FSN__C = inputvalues[1];       
            a.Order_Type__c = inputvalues[3];
            a.Order_Id__c = inputvalues[4];
            a.Order_Item_Id__c = inputvalues[6];
            a.Address_Line_1__c = inputvalues[22];

            orderstoupload.add(a);
        }
        try{
        //insert orderstoupload;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
         }
```

Here Problem is If any One Cell has any  extra "**,**" Then above logic will not Work.

So I am Trying to convert the CSV To Json Then Create a Records out of it.

Want to Know 2 Things

1. How to Convert CSV data To JSON  **OR**
2. Is there a free webservice to convert CSV to JSON which I CAN Use

Comment: You might want to look at this example - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Samples#Parse_a_CSV_with_APEX

Comment: Not a service, but this page http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm gives good insight into formats you might consider. And its good for once-off conversions.

Comment: @KeithC I had Already Seen That site..even it will give me the exact result what i Want..but same site does not provide any API.